# Google Sheet Query

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

I'm currently trying to run a query in Google Sheets, but want to include more data.  Here is my current code:

```
=query('KI Site Visit'!A1:Y38,"Select A,max(D)
    where D is not null
    group by A label max(D)
    'KI Most Recent Visit Date'",1)
```

It returns a list of Names (Column A) and their Most recent (Column D).  I would like to also see associated data for the most recent visits in columns H and Q.  How do I add these columns?

Again I want a list of all Site Visits but only the most recent visits for each person, and I would also like to see the data in Column H and Q for those most recent visits?  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

See if this works:

```
=query('KI Site Visit'!A1:Y38,"Select A,max(D), H, Q where D is not null group by A, H, Q label max(D) 'KI Most Recent Visit Date'",1)
```